# animate.css is loading double time in firefox and chrome

Tags: css, firefox, animation, css-transitions, css3pie

Hi Anyone please help me on this in my page i used fadeInUp css from animate.css file. when i open in firefox it is loading double time.

This is css i used.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
     transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
     transform: none;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;

    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
     transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
     -ms-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -moz-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -ms-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -o-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

some times i am getting same error in chrome also

Answer (score 0):

you have set it up 2 times.

As far as code in @keyframes fadeInUp has all browsers support, you don't need:
@-moz-keyframes fadeInUp {...} and @-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {...}

Comment: I tried this too. Again same problem. I added the facebook plugin for my wordpress site. Is that will affect the animation in any way??

Comment: What is the relevance from this css to fb plugin?oo

Comment: I dont know after i removed the plugin it is working fine. The plugin is OLARK. May be because of this it is loading twice??

Comment: Not sure, so right now you are using my suggestion or not?

Comment: Yes i removed as you suggested. Still problem  is exists.

Comment: without any further examples and links I can't figure out where the problem

Comment: Thanks Oliver White for your support. Finally i found the solution.                  .wow { visibility: hidden; }. This is the class i added in the header. Problem is solved. Thanks for your support once again.